# How to set DataKeyNames for a complex type?

Tags: c#, gridview, binding

My DataSource is a list of

```
new { Product = p, Category = c }
```

I want to set the DataKeyNames to `Product.ID`, but it says the property doesn't exists.

```
ID="grid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Product.ID">
```

How can I bind it?

Comment: seems like reflection can't access child's property.. can't you expose a int property at root level that points to p.ID?

Comment: @Shoaib So I guess I will need to workaround again. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: ID is field or property?

Answer (score 0):

can you put the datakeynames with the complete namespace.

```
ID="grid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="yourNameSpace.Product.ID">
```